# Questions about sessions on Tomcat. 2 war webapps

Tags: session, tomcat, war

I want to ask a couple questions about tomcat session lifecycle if we are deploying it using 2 war files.

We have the situation when we are logged in the first web app (war1) and put in the session some attributes.

After this we open a new tab at the same browser for war2 and then inside filter we are receiving request that contains new session with new cookie.

So, is it possible to somehow share session attributes on 2 different wep apps (2 dofferent war files under 1 tomcat instance).

Is it possible to have 1 session for 2 web applications?

For example if I open 1 tab in the browser for war1 I am getting sesionId 123ASD, and then if I open second tab for war2 it will contain same sessionId: 123ASD.

Is this situation possible ?

Is there any ways to configure Tomcat ?

I have tryid toput this valve inside server.xml file:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" requireReauthentication="true"/>
```

And add crossContext="true" value for `<Context crossContext="true">` at context.xml file but it doesn't helped at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to share sessions across two web applications.

The single-sign-on valve is intended to share authentication information across applications. It does not share sessions.

The `crossContext` attribute on your `<Context>` doesn't do what you think it does. It allows the application to request a `RequestDispatcher` to another context for the purposes of forwarding requests across contexts. You almost never want to do that. It has nothing to do with sessions.